# collection sort multi items

Tags: java

Am currently trying to sort my object by lastname first then first name then date of birth then ssn. But logically I can only come up with is the lastname then the firstname
any tips?

```
public int compareTo(Doctor o) 
{
    int result =  this.lastName.compareTo(o.lastName());

    return result == 0 ?this.firstName.compareTo(((Doctor) o).firstName()):result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First sort on lastname. If the sort value is `0`, sort on firstname. If that result is `0`, sort for date of birth, and so on. You'll have multiple `return` statements, sure, but it's a lot more readable.

As you probably know, a result value of `0` means the two values are equal. In your use case, this should result in an additional sort instead of simply returning the values.

Edit: other answers below have provided exact implementation for this.

Answer (score 1):

Nested if would be better choice to implement this.

```
public int compareTo(Doctor o){
    int result =  this.lastName.compareTo(o.lastName());

    if(result==0){
        result = this.firstName.compareTo(o.firstName());
        if(result==0){
             result = this.dob.compareTo(o.dob());
             if(result==0){
                ....
             }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
public int compareTo(Doctor o) 
{
    int result =  this.lastName.compareTo(o.lastName());
    if (result != 0)
        return result;

    result = this.firstName.compareTo(o.firstName());
    if (result != 0)
        return result;

    result = this.birthDate.compareTo(o.birthDate());
    if (result != 0)
        return result;

    return this.ssn.compareTo(o.ssn());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you may have realized, this is a kind of the "chain of responsibility". So i would suggest you the pattern for this case. [Chain-of-responsibility Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)

It will save you from writing too many if()...s