# Tidying up if/else statements in compareTo method

Tags: java, if-statement

This is a method of a class Employee. It compares two objects of employee, containing four variables: id (an int), name, phone and job title (all Strings).

```
public int compareTo(Employee other) {
    if (this.id == other.id) {
        if (this.name.compareTo(other.name) == 0) {
            if (this.phoneNumber.compareTo(other.phoneNumber) == 0) {
                if (this.jobTitle.compareTo(other.jobTitle) == 0)
                    return 0;
                else if (this.jobTitle.compareTo(other.jobTitle) > 0)
                    return 1;
                else 
                    return -1;
            }
            else if (this.phoneNumber.compareTo(other.phoneNumber) > 0)
                return 1;
            else
                return -1;
        }
        else if (this.name.compareTo(other.name) > 0)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
    else if (this.id > other.id)
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

The code works fine, but I'm aware it's getting to be fairly arrow-shaped, and a little complicated. Does anybody have any advice on clearing up this collection of if/else statements?

**Edit: I'm aware it may seem counter-intuitive to continue comparing after ID, which would logically be unique, but just roll with it!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [collection sort multi items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599048/collection-sort-multi-items/15599114) for examples on how to implement a multi-level order of items.

I think the code can be made much shorter if you simply returned the result of a compareTo call, instead of using if-else and returning 0/1.

Comment: I think I'll go with your answer, and the link you posted to, as I think its the cleanest implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that all your checks have to be == 0, to return 0. If one of them is  > 0, it returns 1 and if else return -1;

So:

```
 if (this.id == other.id &&
     this.name.compareTo(other.name) == 0 &&
     this.jobTitle.compareTo(other.jobTitle) == 0 &&
     this.phoneNumber.compareTo(other.phoneNumber) == 0 ) {
     return 0;
 } else if (this.id > other.id ||
     (this.name.compareTo(other.name) > 0 ||
     this.jobTitle.compareTo(other.jobTitle) > 0 ||
     this.phoneNumber.compareTo(other.phoneNumber) > 0) {
     return 1;
 } else {
     return -1;
 }
```